# Benchmark Systems for ODE Solvers - Reference Request

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, na.numerical-analysis

I would like to have a basic models as a ground truth for the numerical solvers. I am looking for systems which have available analytic solution. As an example I know that the closed form solution of IVP:
\begin{align}
    &\dot{y}(t) = -2y(t)\\
    &y(0) = 1
\end{align}
is:
\begin{align}
    y(t) = e^{-2t}
\end{align}
When using forward euler I know that numerical solution is given by the recurrence relation:
\begin{align}
    &y_k = (1-2\Delta{t})y_{k-1}\\
    &y_0 = y(0)
\end{align}
This gives me a way of calculating **global error** for this specific system:
\begin{align}
e_k = |y_k - y(t_k)|
\end{align}
The problem is that the above system may not be "relevant" as a benchmark for numerical solvers. I am looking for relevant ones as it is much easier to present the results in that case. There are articles on this topic such as
"Hull et al.: Comparing numerical methods for ordinary differential equations" and "Enright et al.: Comparing numerical methods for stiff systems of ODE:s". The problem is that I am looking for a way to present results using a global error. Is there any similar calculating closed form solutions?

Any suggestions and/or critiques are appreciated.

Comment: So you want more complicated systems than the example you presented ?

Comment: @PiyushGrover They should be more complicated in the sense they reveal strengths and weaknesses of different ODE solvers. Another example may be 2nd order linear system with a large stiffness ratio and so on. I could take the time and try to enumerate them, but I am hoping to find a reference that already did something similar. This was already done in mentioned articles, but with local error as one of criteria instead of global error.

Comment: Focussing on systems with closed-form solutions pretty much excludes chaotic systems, which are ones where global error can be severe (butterfly effect etc.)

Comment: @Robert Israel I realize that this is the case and this fine for me. I would like to make experiments with such demonstration systems for introduction purposes.

Comment: You can easily come up with stiff systems which are analytically solvable. Basically, you need the eigenvalues to be of very different sizes, say $\lambda_1=10^3\lambda_2$.

Comment: Not majoring in ODE solvers, but as I recall, benchmark for stiff ODE solvers do not have analytical solution available usually. One of the known authors in this field usually takes Belousov-Zhabotinsky reaction as a benchmark, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a whole subfield of applied mathematics devoted to developing ODE solvers and understanding their properties.  Consequently, there are thousands of relevant papers, and not much more can be said without a more specific question.  The canonical reference, which includes lots of methods tested on lots of ODE systems (with global error as a metric) is

[Hairer, Norsett, Wanner.  Solving ordinary differential equations (2 volumes)](http://www.unige.ch/~hairer/books.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to come up with a differential equation that has a known general solution, expressed in the form $F(t,y) = constant$ where $F$ is differentiable:

$$ \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t} + \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y} y' = 0 $$

Similarly, for a system, expressed in implicit form as

$$ F_i(t, y_1, \ldots, y_n) = c_i,\ i=1 \ldots,n $$
differentiation gives you 
$$ \dfrac{\partial F_i}{\partial t} + \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{\partial F_i}{\partial y_j} y_j' = 0$$
which (when the Jacobian is invertible) you then solve for $y'_1, \ldots, y'_n$.